# where i can find the wacom configuration file in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, files, configuration, wacom

I want to know the location of the configuration file created with the wacom tablet tool in ubuntu 12.04, I want to change the preassure curve and another settings manually..

thanks and have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom as it details the setup of the pressure curve as follows:

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf`

Edit it so it looks like the following with your new Pressure settings:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
    Option        "PressCurve"    "50,0,100,50"
    Option        "Threshold"     "60"
EndSection
```

Save and unplug and re-plug your device.